# C Preprocessor #if string

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way of optionally including code using `#define` like this?

```
#define TIMR_TO_USE TIM14

#if TIMR_TO_USE == TIM14
    // Do some stuff.
#elif TIMR_TO_USE == TIM16
    // Do some other stuff.
#endif
```

I feel like this ought to work but doesn't. Is there a way round it?

For info I want to optionally choose which timer to use on an STM32. I have lots of places where I have code like

```
TIMR_TO_USE->ARR = 1000;
```

But there are other places where I need different lines of code.

Comment: Better do `#define USE_TIM14` and then `#ifdef USE_TIM14 .... #elif defined(USE_TIM16) ... #endif`. But why would you want something "around it"?

Comment: _"where I need different lines of code:"_ it's unclear what you mean, __show__ more sample code instead of __describing__ it.

Comment: You need to define `TIM14` and `TIM16` to different integer values, e.g. 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `TIM14` and `TIM16` are defined as pointers you cannot define these as integers as proposed in a comment but you could use separate preprocessor symbols to select the implementation.

```
#define USE_TIM14
//#define USE_TIM16

#ifdef USE_TIM14
#    define TIMR_TO_USE TIM14
#elif defined(USE_TIM16)
#    define TIMR_TO_USE TIM16
#else
#    error "no timer selected"
#endif

void func(void)
{
#ifdef USE_TIM14
    // Do some stuff.
#elif defined(USE_TIM16)
    // Do some other stuff.
#endif

    TIMR_TO_USE->ARR = 1000;
}
```

The error handling could be improved to also detect if multiple `USE_TIM*` are defined.

Comment: Good guess. That's probably what they're actually trying to achieve.